tee -a command not appending to file in stringed commands
I have the following command that works fine however writing this command in a "more proper" manner, the tee -a fails to append each line to the .log file.  (Instead it overwrites the file with only the last tee output)  I'm just curious as to why the tee -a isn't working as expected in the 2nd example below.
OS: RHEL 8.9 (Shell: zsh)
Properly displays output and appends all three commands to file:
date >> ./net.log | tee && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 4' >> ./net.log | tee && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 6' >> ./net.log | tee 

Properly displays output but does not append to file (overwrites file with last command only):
date | tee -a ./net.log && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 4' | tee -a ./net.log && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 6' | tee -a ./net.log


Have each tee write to a different file.

What are you expecting date >> ./net.log | tee to do? The date output is redirected to the file, so tee doesn't receive anything on its stdin. And tee with no filename argument seems useless.

Your command works for me. The file contents is the same as what gets printed on the terminal.

Are you sure you didn't forget -a on the last command?

you are almost there. try the following
(date && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 4' && ifconfig | awk 'NR == 6') | tee -a ./net.log


Don't just post code. Explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.
